# How to keep Alarm Manager running even after the app closes?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice

I want an AlarmManager in my MainActivity.java file which will trigger an IntentService every minute.

The code I wrote is:

```
public void scheduleAlarm() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MyAlarmReceiver.REQEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, 60000, pendingIntent);
}
```

This is my IntentService:

```
public class MyTestService extends IntentService {

    public MyTestService() {
        super("MyTestService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("tag_tag_tag", "Service running");

        String filename = "example.txt";
        String fileContents = "\ndone ";
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {
            fos = openFileOutput(filename, MODE_APPEND);
            fos.write(fileContents.getBytes());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
       }

    }
}
```

Here I am just appending to a file just to check if the service runs even after the app is closed, and it doesn't.

This is my Receiver:
    public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
    public static final int REQEST_CODE = 12345;
    public static final String ACTION = "com.always_in_beta.bekar";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MyTestService.class);
        i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

I want this service to be triggered every minute in the background even after the app closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of AlarmManager is very unreliable, especially from Android M onward. Alarm events are ignored by phone doze mode. I use Firebase JobDispatcher https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android that serves great for this purposes. Code:
Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
```

Job class:

```
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobParameters;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobService;

public class MyTestService extends JobService {
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
    // something like
 Log.d("tag_tag_tag", "Service running");

    String filename = "example.txt";
    String fileContents = "\ndone ";
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

try {
        fos = openFileOutput(filename, MODE_APPEND);
        fos.write(fileContents.getBytes());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   }

    return false; // Answers the question: "Is there still work going on?"
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
    return false; // Answers the question: "Should this job be retried?"
}
```

}

Manifest:

```
<service
android:exported="false"
android:name=".MyTestService">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

In your activity, create dispatcher:

```
// Create a new dispatcher using the Google Play driver.
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
```

then schedule the job:

```
Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
.setService(MyTestService.class) // the JobService that will be called
.setTag("my-unique-tag")        // uniquely identifies the job
.setRecurring(true)
.setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(1*60-10,1*60+10))//1 minute +/- 10 seconds
.build();

dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

This should work, at least it works for me.

Comment: Will this continue to run even when the app closes?

Comment: Yes, it should. Please check documentation at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android . It should even launch the service after phone reboot if you set jobBuilder flag to .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)

Comment: I want to detect the user's current activity like STANDING, WALKING, IN CAR etc.). But the ActivityRecognitionClient requires an intent to be passed. Can you please help me with any alternatives to that?

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with that. But suppose you could pass an intent in onStartJob event returning true from it(something still happens), then after ActivityRecognitionClient finishes call jobFinished in JobService class.

Comment: I mean, when I try to recognise the current activity of the user, from the service, it initially works, but when I close the app and then the service calls the other service to recognize the activity, the service crashes, saying that service called from background.